# Async and Knex: how they work ?

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I parse an json object and for each element, i need to execute many queries.
In first, a "select" query and depending on the result, i execute an insert or an update.
I would like use async.js and knex.js
The issue it's the order of execution is not the searched order

```
            async.each(newContent,function(e){
                //var e=JSON.stringify(element),
                    var z=-1,
                        devicepresenceId = e.device_presence_id;
                //console.log(e);
                async.waterfall([
                    function(cb) {
                        knex('jos_joomrh_event_employee_hours_presence')
                            .whereRaw('device_presence_id=?', devicepresenceId)
                            .select('id', 'applied_at', 'applied_at_end')
                            .debug()
                            .then(function (rows) {
                                console.log(rows);
                                z = _.keys(rows).length;
                                console.log('rows0', z);
                                cb(null,z);
                            })
                            .catch(function (e) {
                                console.log(e)
                                reject(e)
                            })
                        cb(null,z);
                    },
                    function(z,cb){
                        console.log('z',z);
                        if (parseInt(z)==0)
                        {
                            console.log('insertHoursPresence');
                            //insertHoursPresence(e)
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log('updateHoursPresence');
                            //updateHoursPresence(e)
                        }
                        cb(null,'two')
                    }
                ],
                function(err,z){
                    if(err)console.log(err);
                    console.log(z);
                }
                )}
            )}
```

In fact; it executed the second function and and the cb function and after the first function with knex.:
Thanks for your help
Mdouke

Answer (score 0):

In the knex part, you have a call to "cb(null,z)", you have to "move" that call inside catch function (but replacing reject(e) part). Your problem is that you're calling cb() function outside knex, of course it is called immediately independent of knex result)

Comment: Thanks for your response, it helps me for my futur dev. Mdouke.